# Scipy Optimize: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence on Newton-CG method

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, minimize, valueerror

I'm trying to code my own logistic regression, and compare different methods of maximizing the log-likelihood. Using the Newton-CG method, I get the error message "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence". Reading around, it seems this error rises if the function sought to be minimized returns a non-skalar, but that is not the case here. I need the three methods given below to give the same result (approximately), but when running on my real data, one does not converge, and the other one gives a worse LL than the initial guess, and the third does not run at all.

Why do I get the ValueError message and how can I fix it?

My code (with dummy data, the real data is ~100 measurements) is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import minimize
def CalcLL(beta,xinlist,yinlist):
    LL=0.0
    ncol=len(beta)
    pi=FindPi(xinlist,beta.reshape(ncol,1))
    for i in range(len(yinlist)):
        LL=LL+np.where(yinlist[i]==1,np.log(pi[i]),np.log(1-pi[i]))
    return -LL
def Jacobian(beta,xinlist,yinlist):
    ncol=len(beta)
    nrow=np.shape(xinlist)[0]
    pi=FindPi(xinlist,beta.reshape(ncol,1))
    Jac=np.transpose(np.matrix(yinlist-pi))*np.matrix(xinlist)
    return Jac
def Hessian(beta,xinlist,yinlist):
    ncol=len(beta)
    nrow=np.shape(xinlist)[0]
    pi=FindPi(xinlist,beta.reshape(ncol,1))
    W=FindW(pi)
    Hes=np.matrix(np.transpose(xinlist))*(np.matrix(W)*np.matrix(xinlist))
    return Hes
def FindPi(xinlist,beta):
    rows=np.shape(xinlist)[0]# Number of rows in x_new
    cols=np.shape(xinlist)[1]# Number of columns in x_new
    expon=np.dot(xinlist,beta)
    expon=np.array(expon).reshape(rows,1)
    pi=np.exp(expon)/(1+np.exp(expon))
    return pi
def FindW(pi):
    W=np.zeros(len(pi)*len(pi)).reshape(len(pi),len(pi))
    for i in range(len(pi)):
        W[i,i]=float(pi[i]*(1-pi[i]))
    return W

xinlist=np.matrix([[1,1],[0,1],[1,1],[1,1],[1,1],[0,1],[0,1],[1,1],[1,1],[0,1]])
yinlist=np.transpose(np.matrix([0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]))

ncol=np.shape(xinlist)[1]

beta1=np.zeros(ncol).reshape(ncol,1) # Initial guess for parameter values
limit=0.000001 # selfwritten Newton-Raphson method
iter_i=limit+1
while iter_i>limit:
    Hes=Hessian(beta1,xinlist,yinlist)
    Jac=np.transpose(Jacobian(beta1,xinlist,yinlist))
    root_diff=np.array(linalg.inv(Hes)*Jac)
    beta1=beta1+root_diff
    iter_i=np.sum(root_diff*root_diff)
print "When running self-written algorithm, the log-likelihood is",-CalcLL(beta1,xinlist,yinlist)

beta2=np.zeros(ncol).reshape(ncol,1)
res=minimize(CalcLL,beta2,args=(xinlist,yinlist),method='Nelder-Mead',options={'xtol':1e-8,'disp':True,'maxiter':10000})
beta2=res.x
print "The log-likelihood using Nelder-Mead is", -CalcLL(beta2,xinlist,yinlist)

beta3=np.zeros(ncol).reshape(ncol,1)
res=minimize(CalcLL,beta3,args=(xinlist,yinlist),method='Newton-CG',jac=Jacobian,hess=Hes,options={'xtol':1e-8,'disp':True})
beta3=res.x
print "The log-likelihood using Newton-CG is", -CalcLL(beta3,xinlist,yinlist)
```

EDIT:
The errorstack is as follows:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "MyLogisticRegression2.py", line 62, in 
   res=minimize(CalcLL,beta3,args=(xinlist,yinlist),method='Newton-CG',jac=Jacobian,hess=Hes,options={'xtol':1e-8,'disp':True})

File C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize_minimize.py, line 447, in minimize **options)

File C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py, line 2393, in _minimize_newtoncg eta=numpy.min([0.5, numpy.sqrt(maggrad)])

File C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py, line 2393, in amin out=out, **kwargs)

File C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_methods.py, line 29, in _amin return umr_minimum(a,axis,None,out,keepdims)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Comment: FYI:  The same error is raised if, for example, you try to assign a list or array to an element in an array.  e.g., `A = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]); A[0] = [6,7]`

Comment: What function produces this error message?  Give some, if not all, of the error stack.  It's not fair to us to say there's an error, and then not tell us where.

Comment: Not an error, but `np.zeros(ncol).reshape(ncol,1)` can be written as `np.zeros((ncol, 1))`.  If `expon` is not a scalar, then `np.array(expon).reshape(rows,1)` can just be `expon.reshape(rows,1)`.  I'd also encourage you to not use `np.matrix`; better to stick with `np.array`.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem rose from beta arrays having shape (2,1) instead of (2,), and likewise for the Jacobian. Reshaping these two solved the problem.

The Newton-CG solver needs only 1d arrays for the Jacobian apparently.